# How to discard Destiny's Festival of the Lost items?

Tags: destiny

Now that Destiny's Festival of the Lost has expired, I still have consumable items left over. How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get rid of them is to use them (assuming you're talking about Jackolytes and Flights of Shadow). There is no option to discard them that I'm aware of.

I just stuck them in my vault.

Comment: This has really grinded my gears about some other consumables like Fusion Rifle Telemetry. Got a handful of those for some reason, that I'll probably never make use of (I generally abhor Fusion Rifles), but the only way to get rid of them is to actually use one... then wait for the cooldown and use another... rinse and repeat until the supply is exhausted.

Comment: Sounds like the only solution.

Comment: @Iszi Yeah, they aren't easy to get rid of. You can always use one just before you are done playing (since the timer is based on real time, not game time), and eventually you'll get rid of them.